# Loop through MAC addresses, how to handle both numbers (0-9) and letters (a-f) in a "for" loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, mac-address

I've a script with this code

```
for i in {2..9}
        do 
        grep "Node${i}\|01, source address = 00:00:00:00:00:0${i}" t1.txt > t2.txt
        done
```

Is it possible to expand the loop from "9" to the "f" character of the exadecimal MAC address, in order to handle the "a" to "f" cases too?

Comment: You mean `for i in {2..9} {a..f}; do ...`? Is that enough? That will just include the letters between a and f in your current locale.

Comment: Yep that works, I mean I also bruteforced with a 
for i in 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
Not pretty but it works too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add another brace expansion for the letters:

```
for i in {2..9} {a..f}
do 
    grep "Node${i}\|01, source address = 00:00:00:00:00:0${i}" t1.txt > t2.txt
done
```

Note that this is likely not what you really want. Each time this code runs, it will overwrite the contents of `t2.txt` which means you will only ever see the results for the final iteration. If that didn't match, you'll have an empty file even if something else did match. Maybe you want to append instead:

```
for i in {2..9} {a..f}
do 
    grep "Node${i}\|01, source address = 00:00:00:00:00:0${i}" t1.txt >> t2.txt
done
```

Or, more likely, you don't need a loop at all and should instead do this:

```
grep -E 'Node[2-9a-f]|01, source address = 00:00:00:00:00:0[2-9a-f]' t1.txt > t2.txt
```